# How to run node.js file from PHP file

Tags: node.js

so I've been trying to run an SMS script after the user submits a form. 
If I use

```
node send-sms.js
```

locally on my machine, it works. 
However, if I try to use

```
$sendSmsPath = "send-sms.js";
exec('/public_html/node_modules/node '.$sendSmsPath);
```

Nothing happens. No error, nothing. I tried using a relative path, as well as an absolute one. My folder scheme is as follows: public > other_folder > php > php_file.php AND public > node_modules

Any ideas are welcome, thanks

Comment: Run the command `which node` and tell me the output?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I run it on my machine, it returns "/c/Program Files/nodejs/node"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong path to Node.js. Try this:

```php
<?php
$sendSmsPath = "send-sms.js";
exec('/c/Program Files/nodejs/node '.$sendSmsPath);
```

`node_modules` is for the dependencies of your script, not the actual Node.js executable.

If you'd like to run your script on another machine make sure it has Node.js installed globally and you know the path of the executable (can be found with `which node`)

Comment: Well, yes, but I need it on the public host. So that path is not good for me. Can I install node to my workspace folder?

Comment: @ToniFlorea You would have to talk with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

return or print your values in your js file so you will get these variabales in your output

```php
$output = shell_exec('node C:\xampp\htdocs\noah-imports\app\NodeJs\index.js');
```